# Meaning of "Что ни день"

Tags: значения

This is a comment I saw in a forum. Is it a typo, or does it actually mean something?

> Что ни день, то приключение!

Comment: "Что не день, то приключение!"  -  It could mean   "this is the night - this is an adventure!".

Comment: " you can use ", by the way", but without but. " - i used but there because i wanted to emphasize the "however" for this "by the way"... and for "introduce a word or phrase that contrasts with what was said before." :)

Comment: @Пилум: it doesn't make sense. We don't write that way.

Comment: well, i said about logic and intuition yet :>

Comment: тут же учат именно русский и группа русского языка, не так ли ? :)

Comment: What is it with you two and the bickering about English?

Comment: Что ни делается, всё к лучшему///Тотальная "пробка" на дороге: что ни едет, всё стоит

Comment: Not bickering. I *know* English — I'm a professional editor. I just struggle to understand Pilum's English (e.g. well, i said about logic and intuition yet) and he resists correction.

Comment: CocoPop Because You really change the meaning of translations and censor the posts intentionally or not. You must not corrupt messages. " I'm a professional editor." - And Your name is the William, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Can you write it in Russian?

Comment: CocoPop, Извольте. Положительно, перевода смысл искажаете вы и посты цензурируете, умышленно или нет. Вы не должны сообщения коверкать. 
" I'm a professional editor." - И Уильямом наречены, не так ли ? :> ... 
" I don't understand what you're saying. " -Тогда тем паче не стоит в такие все тяжкие пускаться, возможно ?  :>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a real sentence, but the poster incorrectly used "не" where they should've used "ни". The correct form of the sentence is:

> Что ни день, то приключение!

which means:

> Not a day passes without some adventure!

*"Что ни день"* means *"every day"*, but is more literally translated as *"any given day"* or *"any passing day"*.

Comment: How interesting, Lila, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good description of this structure, from [Учебно-тренировочные тесты по русскому языку как иностранному В2-С1 — Грамматика. Лексика (Learning and Training Tests in Russian as a Foreign Language. Volume 1. Grammar. Vocabulary), p. 115](https://vdocuments.mx/learning-and-training-tests-in-russian-as-a-foreign-language-volume-1-grammar.html):

> **5.1. Грамматическая стилистика: некоторые конструкции, характерные для разговорной, эмоционально окрашенной речи**
>
> Представленные здесь конструкции речи характерны для разговорного стиля и имеют экспрессивную окраску.
>
> 1. Конструкция *что ни ..., то ...* передаёт значение повторяющихся действий или явлений: *У него **что ни день, то** какое-нибудь приключение; У этой певицы **что ни песня, то** шедевр.*
>
>    Такие предложения синонимичны высказываниям со словом *каждый: У этого спортсмена **что ни выступление, то** новый рекорд. — У этого спортсмена **каждое выступление** — новый рекорд.*

Comment: VCN250, that's a great explanation! Thank you. I'm curious, where did you find that?

Comment: It's from a grammar preparing students to the second level Russian Proficiency Test. Well, it's just a collection of grammar tips etc, but to be honest this little book solved a hell of a lot of problems for me—виды, краткие прилагательные и тд )) 

here's what the series is called—Learning and Training Tests in Russian as a Foreign Language. Volume 1. Grammar. Vocabulary.pdf

Comment: The grammar tips are in the back of this book. —And by the way))—http://translate.academic.ru/что%20ни%20то/ru/en/

Comment: Thank you indeed, I'll see if I can find it. And thank you for the link!